# Have a column span all rows as one cell SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

[image: Desired output]

I want to use ssrs to replicate this picture where the right column spans all the rows in the table. Right now I'm using a tablix with SSRS 2008.

Comment: Do you have any grouping of your data? Or just details? Also, will the IDC Comment will be static text? Or it will output some data from dataset?

Comment: No groupings in my table right now just details. IDC Comment will be static

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tablix with only two columns and one row, delete the details group.

[image]

Then drag the tablix with your data and drop it inside the first cell of the previous created tablix.

[image]

The outer tablix contains in its first cell the inner tablix which contains the dynamic data.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This got me closer but the static content in your example doesn't have a header

Comment: @AmericanSuave, right click the Static content cell and select `Insert row` / `Above`.

Comment: This doesn't work as now I just have an extra row above my original table and the header of the static column is not in line with the headers of the original table

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you can put the Column on the right, but i could put it on the left.

Create a group on something that all the records have in common. In my example, All Customers are for the same Company.

[image]

This Group box label can be overwritten with another field, or rectangle to make the box Free Form for the Data that you need to spand across all records. Overwriting this field does not delete the group.

Here is the end result:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately these records don't have a common field and it is required to be on the right side